# Local C# lock for a method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

All the [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock#example)/examples I have seen regarding C# `lock` are using a class member variable for locking.

Instead of using a class member variable, I want to use a local variable for locking the execution of a particular section of the code.

**My Sample Code:**

```
class TestClass
{
    public static int TestMethod()
    {
        // some code
        
        foreach (var example in Examples)
        {
            //some code...
            
            object myLock = new object(); // QUESTION: Is this valid?
            Parallel.ForEach(AllChunks, (chunk) =>
            {
                // some code...
                
                lock(myLock)
                {
                    // do some GPU related activities
                }
            }
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am using `myLock` (a local variable inside `TestMethod()`) to lock the execution of a particular section of the code.

**QUESTION:** Is this implementation valid and correct? My lock is not `readonly` (as suggested in tutorials).

Comment: If that is the only place you need to lock and you only want to lock the "chunks" against each other shown here that should work. "readonly" is disallowed for local variables but i assume you are not going to change the myLock variable somewhere in the parallel foreach.

Comment: If you call this method twice then you will have two Parallel.ForEach simultaneously with GPU related activities that will have their own lock object

Comment: @Serhii: If I call this method twice but sequentially then, it shouldn't be a problem. But if this method itself gets called more than once on different threads then, the actual problem will start because each Thread will have its own lock, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine.

<sup>(Sorry this answer is so short, but there is nothing else to say really)</sup>